# Laravel Queue processing in a loop

Tags: laravel

I have a table of queues in my database. I have event and its listeners. I want to run them by the command `php artisan queue:work`
but one of my listeners which is supposed to send an email to the user, doesn't get processed and it gets stuck in an indefinite loop of processing...I know that I can limit the amount of processing by --tries=3 but I don't know how to get the listener processed properly...

[Here is the listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiGoe.png)

[I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWtua.png)